# Add new field to report - Script - NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to run a report from a script.
The script works fine
Need to add a new field that indicates if the user is admin or not.

I am not sure how to add that with a true or false condition.
Right now it is returning undefined or false.

The field in mongo database is this one:
[mongo-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9fN1.png)

```
var orderTotalsByUserId = {}; 
db.orders.aggregate([{ $match: { completed: { $exists: true }, completed: { $gt : new Date('2020-08-01') } } }, { $group: { _id: { userId : "$userId" }, total : { $sum: "$total"} } }]).forEach( d => orderTotalsByUserId[d._id.userId] = d.total )

var userIdsByOrders = db.orders.aggregate([{ $match: { completed: { $exists: true }, completed: { $gt : new Date('2020-08-01') } } }, { $group: { _id: { userId : "$userId" }, total : { $sum: "$total"} } }]).map( d => ObjectId(d._id.userId) )

var customers = {};
db.organizations.find().forEach(c => { customers[c._id.valueOf()] = c });

db.users.find({ _id: { $in: userIdsByOrders } }).forEach(d => print(`${d.firstName}, ${d.lastName}, ${d.profile.email}, ${customers[d.customerId].name},${d.sensitive.active.globalAdmin}, ${(orderTotalsByUserId[d._id.valueOf()] * .01).toFixed(2)}`) )
```

Comment: The ${d.featurePermissions.user_management} field indicates if the user is admin or not

Comment: Just to explain. It happens that the field I rounded in the mongo-database image I uploaded, is not the required field. I will leave it here for better understanding of the db structure. In the answer code you can check the correct field for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I've been able to solve it.
Hope it can be helpful for someone else.

First filtering the featurePermissions field in the pipeline.
Then, created an if statement, indicating that if the user has a Customer, it should print the following values.

The solution was:

```
var orderTotalsByUserId = {}; 
db.orders.aggregate([{ $match: { completed: { $exists: true }, completed: { $gt : new Date('2020-08-01') } } }, { $group: { _id: { userId : "$userId" }, total : { $sum: "$total"} } }]).forEach( d => orderTotalsByUserId[d._id.userId] = d.total );

var customers = {};
db.organizations.find().forEach(c => { customers[c._id.valueOf()] = c });

db.users.find({ featurePermissions: { $exists: true } }, { _id: 1, firstName: 1, lastName: 1, profile: 1, customerId: 1, featurePermissions: 1 }).forEach(d => { if (customers[d.customerId]) { print(`${d.firstName}, ${d.lastName}, ${d.profile.email}, ${customers[d.customerId].name}, ${orderTotalsByUserId[d._id.valueOf()] ? (orderTotalsByUserId[d._id.valueOf()] * .01).toFixed(2) : 0 }, ${d.featurePermissions.user_management ? 'true' : 'false' }`)}});
```